# Remove Email Ids from a Strings

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have a string with multiple email and need to only remove the email address from the string. Tried using the regexp but not exactly sure how to keep the other text but only remove the emails

```
David Ram:DRAM@info.au,Seja:SEJA@info.au,Yogan:YSGAN@info.au
```

Query:

```
 SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(TEXTAREA,':[a-zA-z0-9.]@[a-zA-z0-9.]*' )  FROM CONTEXT
```

Output:

```
David Ram,Seja,Yogan
```

Comment: Please clarify if all emails have same domain. Also, are those emails some kind of local emails, issued by some company rules? Because if not - local part of email [can contain more symbols than just digits, letters and dots](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2049510/21363224)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one option:

```
SQL> with test(col) as
  2    (select 'David Ram:DRAM@info.au,Seja:SEJA@info.au,Yogan:YSGAN@info.au' from dual)
  3  select regexp_replace(col, ':\w+@\w+\.\w+') result
  4  from test;

RESULT
--------------------
David Ram,Seja,Yogan

SQL>
```

Comment: I believe you have missed ``\`` before `.` in regex (or was it intentional?) Also, this will work for example supplied in question, but will produce undesired output for emails with domain of more then two levels, like `yourquestions@bbc.co.uk`.

Comment: And also-also it will left any email with `.` in local part, like `name.surname@mail.com`

Comment: Yes, I missed \, thank you (fixed), @markalex. As of *undesired output*, well ... that's sample data OP provided, I don't know what they have (or don't have).

Answer (score 1):

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/5ZWcchqS)

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(TEXTAREA,':(.*?),',',' )  
FROM (SELECT 'David Ram:DRAM@info.au,Seja:SEJA@info.au,Yogan:YSGAN@info.au'||',' TEXTAREA from dual)
```